Swift: Not playing user recorded audio - OSStatus Error 1685348671
I'm working on an iOS application using Swift where I need to play user created audio files. However when it comes to loading the file, I'm encountering an issue when trying to initialize AVAudioPlayer with user created audio, but works for Bundle audio assets.
Here's the error I receive:

Failed to initialize AVAudioPlayer: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1685348671.)

import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

struct ParentView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIImagePickerController


    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {

        let soundSelectorButtonSize: CGFloat = 50
        let soundSelectorButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: overlayView.bounds.height - soundSelectorButtonSize - 100, width: soundSelectorButtonSize, height: soundSelectorButtonSize))
        if let image = UIImage(systemName: "music.note", withConfiguration: symbolConfigSmall) {
            soundSelectorButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        }
        soundSelectorButton.tintColor = .white
        soundSelectorButton.backgroundColor = .clear
        soundSelectorButton.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.showSoundSelector), for: .touchUpInside)


        let recordButton = UIButton()
        recordButton.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.startRecording), for: .touchDown)
        recordButton.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.stopRecording), for: [.touchUpInside, .touchUpOutside])
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) { }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {
    var parent: ParentView
    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder?
    var audioURL: URL?

    init(_ parent: CameraView) {
        self.parent = parent
        super.init()
        setupAudioRecorder()
    }

    func setupAudioRecorder() {
        let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
        ]

        let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        audioURL = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("mySuperCoolApp.m4a")

        do {
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioURL!, settings: settings)
            audioRecorder?.prepareToRecord()
        } catch {
            print("Error setting up the audio recorder:", error)
        }
    }

    @objc func startRecording(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Recording started")
        audioRecorder?.record()
    }

    @objc func stopRecording(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Recording ended")
        audioRecorder?.stop()
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: audioURL!.path) {
            print("File saved!")
        } else {
            print("File did not save.")
        }
    }

        @objc func showSoundSelector() {
            if let audioURL = audioURL, FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: audioURL.path) {
                print("Custom sound file exists at \(audioURL)")
            } else {
                print("Custom sound file does not exist.")
            }
            let soundOptions = ["audio1", "audio2", "audio3", "audio4"]
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Select Sound", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            
            let customAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Custom Sound", style: .default) { _ in
                self.loadSound(isCustom: true)
            }
            
            for option in soundOptions {
                let action = UIAlertAction(title: option, style: .default) { _ in
                    self.loadSound(named: option)
                }
                alert.addAction(action)
            }
            
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: audioURL!.path) {
                alert.addAction(customAction)
            }
            
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(cancelAction)
            
            
            parent.imagePicker.present(alert, animated: true)
        }

        func loadSound(named name: String = "Recording", isCustom: Bool = false) {
            var sound: URL?

            if isCustom { //USER RECORDED AUDIO
                if let audioURL = audioURL, FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: audioURL.path) {
                    sound = audioURL
                    print("Custom sound file exists at \(audioURL)")
                } else {
                    print("Custom audio file not found.")
                    return
                }
            } else {
                if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "m4a") {
                    sound = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
                } else {
                    print("Bundled audio file \(name) not found.")
                    return
                }
            }

            if let soundURL = sound {
                do {
                    print(soundURL)
                    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL) //TODO: Error Occurring here!
                    audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
                } catch {
                    print("Failed to initialize AVAudioPlayer: \(error.localizedDescription)") 
                }
            } else {
                print("Sound URL is nil.")
            }
        }
}

The funny thing is this worked first time I implemented it. No idea what has changed.
Info plist has required usage description.
tried changing the audio file type.
tried preparing audio in multiple areas.

Have you already researched the other solutions here on SO? It seems you need check the URL or the file format.

@LawrenceGimenez Hi, yes I have. I don't believe I have any of those issues resolved by their answers. I could be wrong, maybe I can't see the forrest from the trees. I will update the body the code snippet to make it clear that the locally stored bundles work as expected, but not the user's recording.

Thanks for the answer, I have just glanced at your code but my guess is that AVAudioRecorder or AVAudioPlayer needs to be of stronger type? Maybe during initialization this was deallocated or lost somewhere.

The error is kAudioFileInvalidFileError somtake a closer look at the user created files
